# Exclude pixels from a mean filter based on a threshold

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0

I'm trying to implement the KinectFusion algorithm as described in the [original paper](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/pkohli/papers/uist_2011.pdf). I've got to the section where they compute a depth map pyramid, basically a stack of depth maps sampled at different resolutions. Here's where my question comes in

> the sub-sampled version Dl+1 is computed from Dl by **block averaging**
>   followed by sub-sampling to half the resolution. **Depth values are used
>   in the average only if they are within 3σr of the central pixel** to
>   ensure smoothing does not occur over depth bound- aries

(emphasis mine)

I'd like my implementation to run in real-time, so I don't want to throw in a nested for loop, but I don't see any other way to exclude depth values outside the threshold.

I've investigated

[`boxFilter`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=blur#void%20boxFilter(InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20int%20ddepth,%20Size%20ksize,%20Point%20anchor,%20bool%20normalize,%20int%20borderType)), [`filter2D`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga27c049795ce870216ddfb366086b5a04), and [`blur`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=blur#blur), and none of them seem to have a parameter which can exclude pixels based on a threshold

This seems like a compromise between mean and median filtering, but before you say bilateral, I'd like to stick as close to the original implementation as possible. The authors know what bilateral filtering is and use it in a previous section, so they clearly knew about it and could have used it if they wanted to. I may do future experiments with substituting bilateral filtering, but that is not the solution I am looking for.

**Are there any functions that would help be do this efficiently? Or do I need to use a nested for loop?**

Here's my current for-loop implementation

```
 cv::Mat pyramid(cv::Mat& imgMat){
        cv::Mat aveMat(imgMat); // Make a copy of my image for storing the averages
        for(int row = 0; row < aveMat.rows; row++){
            for(int col=0; col  <aveMat.cols; col++){

                //Select the block around the current pixel including edge cases
                int startY = row-1;
                if(row == 0)
                    startY = row;

                int endY = row +1;
                if(row + 1 == aveMat.rows)
                    endY = row;

                int startX = col-1;
                if(col == 0)
                    startX = col;

                int endX = col+1;
                if(col + 1 == aveMat.cols)
                    endX = col;

                cv::Mat block = imgMat(cv::Range(startY, endY), cv::Range(startX, endX));
                float curVal = imgMat.at<float>(row, col);

                //Use the mean function with a mask to select values meeting the threshold
                cv::Scalar meanVal = cv::mean(block, block<(curVal+SIGMA)&block>(curVal-SIGMA));
                aveMat.at<float>(row,col)=meanVal[0];
            }
        }

        //Subsample averaged image at half resolution
        cv::Mat outMat;
        cv::resize(aveMat, outMat, cv::Size(), 0.5, 0.5, cv::INTER_NEAREST);
        return outMat;
    }
```

Comment: why don't you create a mask with your desired threshold? That is pretty straightforward right?

Comment: The threshold changes depending on the value of the central pixel for the block. I think it wouldn't be possible to make a mask for the whole image without a for-loop.